# Windows Server 2016 setup stuck after product key entered

Tags: setup, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2016 standard on a desktop computer with 2 SATA HDDs, using a burnt DVD which is in a SATA DVD drive. I believe it's an AMD CPU with 6 cores, not sure about the exact model # though.

- After downloading the ISO, i verified the SHA1 using MS FCIV tool. Then burned it using the slowest speed (4x).
  (My first attempt didn't work with "missing media driver" error because either the ISO was corrupt or the DVD wasn't burnt well, so I re-downloaded the ISO and re-burnt a new DVD to solve that issue.)
- The target computer booted from the DVD, asked me for language choice, then showed the product key dialog.
- I entered the correct product key and pushed "Next". Now all buttons in the dialog are disabled. However, the setup is not completely hung, command prompt opens by pushing Shift-F10, and the setup log file at `x:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log` shows some entries regarding product key as of the time when I entered the key and pushed next (which was about an hour ago at this point).

What should I do? One person online had a similar issue with a different version of Windows and just waited for a few hours and it worked after that - should I wait, too? Others suggest using a USB drive to do the install but I'm failing to see how that should resolve the issue - I'm pretty sure the DVD was created correctly.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!!

Comment: Do a hard shutdown and reboot to the hard drive you tried to install to, see if the install picks up where it left off, if not start a clean install again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a bootable USB flash disk and installing from it - as was suggested by quite a few people online. My initial hesitation to do so was caused by the fact that a roughly equal number of people online suggested that USB installation was problematic, especially with USB 2 vs USB 3, etc. and DVD **is the way** to go. I've always installed all previous versions of Windows using a CD/DVD - this is the first time I ran into issues with it.

Basically, try burning a DVD first, if it doesn't work, create a bootable USB (in that order because creating a bootable USB is a bit more complicated than burning a DVD).